# libGDX spiriteBatch.draw() not positioning at the right place

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Here is a sample code that is not correctly functioning for me, am I doing something wrong?

```
textureCharacter = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/character1.png")); 

if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
    spriteBatch.draw(textureCharacter, Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY());
}
```

When I touch the the SpiriteBatch at the location X=5 and Y=5 (for example) it draws me the texture at X 5 but Y is the Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 5px ??? By moving the input Y down, the texture moves up...

Gdx.input.getX() and Gdx.input.getY() are returning the values: X=5, Y=5

What I'm trying to do is just move the texture to the input positions I'm touching/moving.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Screen coordinates are not necessarily the same as model-space coordinates.  What does your camera definition look like?  (Since that defines the mapping of model space to the screen.)  The `Gdx.intput.getX()` call returns a point in screen space.

The Y-axis (by default) points in opposite directions on the screen and in GL space.   (grows down from the top of the screen in screen coordinates, and grows up towards the top of the screen in GL coords).  You can either fix your camera to match the screen coordinates or map your touch coordinates into GL coordinates.

See the call to `camera.unproject()` in:
https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/source/browse/trunk/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/examples/MoveSpriteExample.java